# volley POST json object and receive json object from RESTful API

Tags: android, json, rest, http-headers, android-volley

I want send a POST request with json data as the body to a REST api receive a JSON response. I am using JsonObjectRequest and I understand that setting a jsonObject in the JsonObjectRequest constructor sends the request as POST, otherwise as GET. I tried executing the request on postman and it works fine but on android, it gives me error 405 (Method Not Allowed). The REST API also requires me to send `Content-Type: application/json` as a header. Here is my code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(LOGIN_ENDPOINT , payload,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {                           
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("Response")
                            .setContentText(response.toString())
                            .setConfirmText("Ok")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();

                                }

                            })
                            .show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
        pDialog.dismiss();
        new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Error")
                .setContentText(VolleyErrors.getVolleyErrorMessages(error, LoginActivity.this))                        
                .setConfirmText("Ok")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                })
                .show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        return payload.toString().getBytes();

    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return params;
    }
};


RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);

requestQueue.add(req);
```

Comment: Try adding "Request.Method.POST" in your constructor

Comment: I had tried that earlier. same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was in the REST API, it was returning the correct expected response but with an error code 405 rather than the expected 200 so volley used to pick it as an error. I talked to the organization in charge of the REST API and they fixed. The code above works fine, many thanks though for all you who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();   

     //Pass Payload as JSON object like this

       params.put("user_id", user_id);
       params.put("user_password", password);

 JSONObject payload= new JSONObject(params);


 JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,LOGIN_ENDPOINT,payload,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {                           
                pDialog.dismiss();
                new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Response")
                        .setContentText(response.toString())
                        .setConfirmText("Ok")
                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                

          pDialog.dismiss();
          new SweetAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
            .setTitleText("Error")
            .setContentText(VolleyErrors.getVolleyErrorMessages(error, LoginActivity.this))                        
            .setConfirmText("Ok")
            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                      sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                  }
          })
            .show();
         }
       }) {

       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

         HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
         headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
         return headers;
      }

   };

   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);

   requestQueue.add(req);
```